# Why is Error.prototype a d {name: "Error", message: ""}, when Boolean.prototype is a Boolean {}?

Tags: javascript, prototype, ecmascript-5

Environment:
- Chrome console

I understand:

```
Boolean.prototype;  // Boolean {}
Number.prototype;  // Number {}
```

I can't understand:

```
Error.prototype;  // d {name: "Error", message: ""}
```

Question:

- Error` is different, why?
- Specification?
- meaning of the d?

Comment: Not sure about `d` (could be a bug in Chrome), but the rest is [part of the language specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.3.1).

Comment: I'm inclined to write this off as some kind of weirdness of the Chrome console itself.  What difference does it make anyway?

Comment: There is no specification for the behavior of developer consoles.

Answer (score 0):

> Error` is different, why?

Because your console likes to show `name` and `message` properties of error objects, even if they're not enumerable.

> Specification?

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.4. You surely could have found that yourself.

> meaning of the d?

None.